SwiftUI: Implementing Redo with UndoManager while avoiding Sendable closure warnings
(For some context, I'm familiar with Swift but fairly new to Swift concurrency; But I understand the basic concepts) I'm trying to implement undo/redo functionality using UndoManager, but I encountered a compiler warning when I add the redo implementation:
Capture of 'undoManager' with non-sendable type 'UndoManager?' in a `@Sendable` closure; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

Here's the simplified implementation:
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model: MyModel = .init()
    
    func exampleIntent(with undoManager: UndoManager? = nil) {
        undoablyPerform(with: undoManager) {
            model.changeSomething()
        }
    }
    
    private func undoablyPerform(with undoManager: UndoManager? = nil, doit: () -> Void) {
        let oldModel = model
        doit()
        undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self) { targetSelf in
            self.undoablyPerform(with: undoManager) { // Implements redo, but captures UndoManager inside @Sendable closure
                targetSelf.model = oldModel
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm registering the undo action itself inside the registerRedo() function to implement redo, and this seems to me a common approach to implement redo. I understand why the compiler is throwing this warning at me (because UndoManager is not Sendable, let alone the Optional type UndoManager?), but not the proper approach to implement the redo feature.
Surely I can't be the only one encountering this issue... Is there any other way to implement the redo functionality to avoid this warning? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You have to convert the old completion handlers to async/await. You can watch “Meet async/await” for an example

I’m not sure if I’ve used a completion handler in my code. Could you explain it to me in more detail?

You have, twice

How about storing an instance of UndoManager in the ViewModel instead? Do you actually need to support multiple UndoManagers?

@Sweeper That would be a viable approach to fix the warning, but if I don't use the UndoManager provided by Environment(\.undoManager), I wouldn't get the system provided keyboard shortcuts / three finger swipe gesture support. Is this the only workaround?

I've managed to resolve the problem by injecting the UndoManager into my ViewModel and use the undoManager property in my ViewModel directly, instead of using the undoManager passed as a parameter:
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model: MyModel = .init()
    var undoManager: UndoManager?
    
    func exampleIntent() {
        undoablyPerform {
            model.changeSomething()
        }
    }
    
    private func undoablyPerform(doit: () -> Void) {
        let oldModel = model
        doit()
        undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: self) { targetSelf in
            self.undoablyPerform {
                targetSelf.model = oldModel
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.undoManager = undoManager // Injects the UndoManager into the ViewModel
            }
    }
}

With this approach, I'm storing an instance of UndoManager in the ViewModel instead, which resolves the warning effectively. Thanks to the inspiration provided by @Sweeper's comment above!

Since this is SwiftUI the View struct is supposed to be your view model which is designed to have less chance of consistency bugs than using objects. So it doesn't make sense to put your own object on top of the struct. SwiftUI diffs the view model structs and uses that to manage the actual view objects layer automatically for you (choosing different ones depending on the context and platform).

Thank you for sharing your thoughts! I’m trying to fully understand your perspective, but I’m having a bit of trouble grasping the point about avoiding placing my own object on top of the struct. When you mention ‘struct,’ are you referring to the View? And when you mention ‘your own object,’ are you referring to the viewModel? Or am I missing something here? Really sorry if I misinterpreted...

Yes exactly, remove the ViewModel and use multiple View instead, with @State, @Binding, computed vars and computing bindings, try to get the source of truth flow right which can be tricky.

Thanks a lot for your explanation. I’ll try to register the undo/redo actions directly in the View and remove the ViewModel. Much appreciated!
